# Why does TrackValue support 10 dimension values but GetMetric supports only 4 dimension names?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights

Within the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights namespace, the Metric class contains TrackValue methods which support up to 10 dimension values, but the TelemetryClient class has GetMetric methods which support up to 4 dimension names.

My application would like to track 6 dimension values for a metric, but the GetMetric method only supports 4 dimension names.  In my scenario, what will the 5th and 6th dimension names be?

I wrote a small .Net Core application that sends metrics to ApplicationInsights.  When the number of dimension names in the GetMetric call matches the number of dimension values in the TrackValue call, the TrackValue call succeeds.  However, when the number of dimension names doesn't match the number of dimension values, the TrackValue method throws a System.ArgumentException with a message "Attempted to get a metric series by specifying 6 dimension(s) but the metric has 4 dimensions."

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.InstrumentationKey = "AppInsight Instrumentation Key";

var itemMetric = tc.GetMetric("Item", "Amount", "Source", "Locale", "PaymentType");
itemMetric.TrackValue(1.0d, "25", "web", "en-US", "CC", "USD", "US");
```

The call to TrackValue throws the System.ArgumentException detailed above the code.

Is there a way to specify more than 4 dimension names for a Metric so that the TrackValue call will succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage `MetricIdentifier` to `GetMetric()` with 4+ dimensions in the following way:

```
MetricIdentifier id = new MetricIdentifier("namespace", "name", "dim1", "dim2", "dim3", "dim4", "dim5");
Metric myMetric = client.GetMetric(id);
```

The existing overloads are just convenience methods to cover most popular cases with a limited amount of dimensions.